# Highcharts: How to make shared tooltip even when series doesn't have same X value?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

In short: I want to make a shared tooltip for the column chart and scatter chart when the scatter chart doesn't have the same "x" values as the column chart.

This is a minimal reproducible example of my problem:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/Baruch_Levin/wo50t4us/15/

Code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['USA', 'China'],
    },
    yAxis:[{}, {
    opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Corn',
            data: [406292, 260000],
            yAxis: 0
        },
        {
            name: 'Wheat',
            data: [51086, 136000],
            yAxis: 0
        },
        {
                name: 'Benchamrk prev year',
            type: "scatter",
            data: [[-.15,1],[.15,3],[.85,4],[1.15,1]],
            yAxis: 1,
        }
    ]
});
```

I use the scatter plot as a benchmark, to know what was the values in the previous year.
Then I want a shared tooltip that will show me:

```
USA: {some_value}
USA prev year: {some_value}
China: {some_value}
China prev year: {some value}
```

Then I want that also in hover, the column chart AND the scatter plot will be selected.

How can I do that?

I saw this question:
[Highcharts : Shared Tooltip for non-matching x values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093144/highcharts-shared-tooltip-for-non-matching-x-values)

But it doesn't help me, because the jsfiddle there doesn't show how to select on hover both series points etc'
And I am not sure "interpolation" is the right solution, and it was in 2017, maybe now there is another solution...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements. Should the shared tooltip be for the f.e. first column and first dot?  E.g. When hovering `USA Corn 406 column` it should show `USA Corn: 406, Benchmark -0.15`, and analogically when hovering the `Benchmark -0.15 scatter` it should show both `USA Corn: 406, and Benchmark -0.15`?

Comment: @magdalena not exactly. I want to add the scatter data into the shared tooltip for example: in my case will be only two tooltips. one: `USA: corn: 406, corn_benchamrk: 1, wheat: 51, wheat_benchmark: 3` second `China: corn: 260, corn_benchamrk: 4, wheat: 136, wheat_benchmark: 1`. 

And hovering on USA, both series (column and scatter) will be shown without "opacity"

Comment: I created the following prototype: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g72hbp5x/ Let me know if it matches your requirements

Comment: Yes great!! thanks @magdalena !! share it as an answer and i will approve it

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Actually, the mouseover() calculations that I provided in the demo was left over from my previous tests - it's redundant in your case. I've updated the demo and added the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, apply the `tooltip.formatter` with the calculations as follows:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter() {
      let category = this.key,
        tooltipText = '',
        a = [],
        b = [];

      this.series.chart.series.forEach(series => {
        let seriesName = series.name;
        series.points.forEach(point => {
          if (point.category === category || point.category < (this.point.x + 0.5) && point.category > (this.point.x - 0.5)) {

            if (typeof point.category !== 'number') {
              a.push(`<span>${point.category}: ${seriesName}: ${point.y}</span></br>`);
            }
            if (typeof point.category === 'number') {
              b.push(`<span>${point.series.name}: ${point.y}</span></br>`);
            }
          }
        })
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        tooltipText += `${a[i]} ${b[i]}`
      }
      return tooltipText;
        }
      },
```

Additionally, to remove opacity, it will be necessary to modify `series.states`

```
   plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        },
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5vdnmrtw/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states